# thrust::inner_product vs thrust::transform_reduce for finding vector norm

Tags: c++, thrust

I am attempting to calculate the L2 norm of a vector. Originally, I defined my own square operator as follows:

```
template<typename T>                                                            
struct square                                                                   
{                                                                               
    __host__ __device__                                                         
    T operator()(const T& x) const                                              
    {                                                                           
        return x*x;                                                             
    }                                                                           
};
```

and then calculated the norm using

```
result = thrust::sqrt(
    thrust::transform_reduce(
        start, end, thrust::plus<T>(), 0, square<T>());
```

This is very similar to the `norm.cu` [example](https://github.com/thrust/thrust/blob/master/examples/norm.cu) found in Thrust's Git repository. However, I just found out that Thrust provides functionality for calculating an `inner_product`. Using this, I could re-implement my code as follows:

```
result = thrust::sqrt(thrust::inner_product(start, end, start, 0));
```

This is much more concise, and still fairly readable. Is there any reason that the first method was preferred in the Git repository (they're not equivalent, the first method is faster, ...)? I just want to make sure I'm not missing anything.

Comment: I doubt you're missing anything.  The examples are meant to be informative and the value in the norm.cu example is showing how to define functors for transformed reduction.  In this case your performance increase is just a result of the unary_op overhead vs. binary_op overhead.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't sure if the example was just supposed to be educational, or if for some reason it is the recommended approach.